# Find bin where data best fits

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to write a function `get_best_bin` that places a value to its most appropriate bin:

I have a bin which is a list of (start,end) values.

```
def get_best_bin(value, bins):
    return index of bins that the value fits best into.
```

For example

```
bins = [
 (0.0, 0.5),
 (0.5, 1.5),
 (1.5, 3.0),
 (4.5, 5.5)
]

value = [0.4,1.0]
```

And so

```
get_best_bin(value, bins)
```

would return:

```
1
```

because most of the line in `[0.4,1.0]` belongs to the bin `(0.5, 1.5)`. * Note: Even though there is an small intersection with the bin `(0.0, 0.5)`, the majority of the intersection is in `(0.5, 1.5)`*

So far this is what I have tried, but I can only get the possible bins where the intersection exists:

```
possible_bins = set()
for ind,width in enumerate(bins):
    if width[0] <= value[0] <= width[1]:
        possible_bins.add(width)
    if width[0] <= value[1] <= width[1]:
        possible_bins.add(width)
print(possible_bins)

#{(0.0, 0.5), (0.5, 1.5)}
```

I can assume that any value will have some intersection with at least one bin.

Comment: What makes a bin the "correct" bin?

Comment: @Hippolippo  if most of the value range intersects with the bin

Comment: How much of the current `line` is in the `bin` = how long is the intersection = `max(0, min(bin[1], line[1]) - max(bin[0], line[0]))` - because `max(bin[0], line[0])` is the left side of intersection, `min(bin[1], line[1])` is the right, the difference is length - and if it happens the "length" is negative (left and right are the other way around), `max(0, ...)` makes it a 0. Possible bins = any non-0 intersection. Best bin = the one with highest value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
def get_best_bin(value, bins):
    intesections = [min(value[1], b[1]) - max(value[0], b[0]) for b in bins]
    return intesections.index(max(intesections))
```

Explanation:

If there is an intersection, the intersection start at `max(value[0], b[0])` and ends in `min(value[1], b[1])`. so the length of the intersection is `end - start`, meaning `min(value[1], b[1]) - max(value[0], b[0])`.

The list comprehension is creating a list of the intersection lengths (corresponding to each bin), and then you can return the index of the largest number in that list.

Answer (score 1):

The following method should do that job. It is based on average values. However, if you would like to have more complicated selection rules than just the L1 distance it needs modification.

```
import numpy as np

def get_best_bin(value, bins):
    ''' Computes the centers of the bins and checks to which the average value is the closest '''
    return np.argmin(np.absolute(np.mean(bins, 1) - np.mean(value)))

bins = [
 (0.0, 0.5),
 (0.5, 1.5),
 (1.5, 3.0),
 (4.5, 5.5)
]
value = [0.4,1.0]

get_best_bin(value, bins) # returns 1 for the given data
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with this, I may not be the best way and it isn't written as a function:

```
bins = [
 (0.0, 0.5),
 (0.5, 1.5),
 (1.5, 3.0),
 (4.5, 5.5)
]

value = [0.4,1.0]
intersections = []
for x in bins:
    lower = None
    higher = None
    if value[0]<x[1] and value[1]>x[0]:
        lower = x[0] if value[0]<x[0] else value[0]
        higher = x[1] if value[1]>x[1] else value[1]
    else:
        continue
    intersections.append(higher-lower)
bestBin = bins[intersections.index(max(intersections))]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle this problem in a little bit different way.

You have many bins (lets assume they are not sorted).

```
bins = [
  (0.0, 0.5),
  (0.5, 1.5),
  (1.5, 3.0),
  (4.5, 5.5)
  ]
```

You get new value that should correctly classified to a specific bin.

```
 value = (0.4, 1.0)
```

Note that I would use tuple rather than list for value. It is more consistent with your representation of bins and ensures that value is immutable.

Your solution will return all bins that this value is (at least partly) contained in. That's a good start!

To choose *best* bin we can evaluate situation on many different aspects.

As you wrote in in comment:

> [best bin is] if most of the value range intersects with the bin
>   Still we don't know what to do if many of our bins consist of equal parts of value.
>   Assuming you want first bin of those:

```py
def get_first_best_bin(value, bins):
    best_bin = None
    best_quality = 0
    # Iterate on all bins, Changed name width to bin to be consistent in naming
    for ind, bin in enumerate(bins):
        # we need to do evaluation only if value is contained at least partly in current bin
        # basically I made one-liner of your 2 ifs
        if bin[0] <= value[0] <= bin[1] or bin[0] <= value[1] <= bin[1]:
            # If value starts before bin we want edge of bin
            # otherwise value starts somewhere in bin so we calculate from value's start
            start = max(bin[0], value[0])

            # If value ends in bin we want to count up to its end
            # otherwise we take edge of bin
            fin = min(bin[1], value[1])
            # lets check if fit-quality is better now than previous best and choose current bin as best one so far
            if best_quality < fin - start:
                best_bin = bin
    return best_bin
```

If you rather have last best you should use this expression `if best_quality <= fin - start`.

Analogically you could choose *best* bin as bin that is mostly filled with value. Simply change expression to `if best_quality < (fin - start)/(bin[1] - bin[0])`.

Remember that if your value doesn't contain in any of those bins the result will be None.